# Serve other content to search engines without getting penalized?

Tags: javascript, php

I've found some similar questions, but i guess what i'm trying to ask is slightly different:

I'm building a PHP web-application which uses lots of java-script (jQuery) to load/build different parts of the DOM. Also most parts of the website are initially invisible to give them a lovely fade-in effect when they're loaded.

This works all fine, but... I also want the website to be search-engine-friendly. Most search engine bots and spiders won't 'see' the content loaded through java-script. And i guess all the invisible parts can give the website a "high penalize score"?

So, i was thinking of serving search-engine-bots the content 'directly' (without jQuery-loading and all browserstuff) and all html-parts being visible. This way, the bot or spider will get initially the same content but in a different way. But is it safe to detect bots and treat them this way without getting penalized by search engines?

Here's a (very) simplified example of what i mean to do:

Serverscript:

```php
<?php
    // script to detect a bot
    $isBot = detectBot();

    // make the content-div visible or invisible based on $isBot
    $contentClass = $isBot ? "visible" : "hidden";

    // The pagecontent-container
    echo "<div id='content' class='$contentClass'>";

        // if visitor is a bot, then serve the pagecontent at once
        if ( $isBot ) {
            include_once "pages/page.php";
        }

    echo "</div>";
?>
```

Browserscript:

```js
// browserscript to load the pagecontent for a 'human' user when the DOM is loaded
$(document).ready(function() {
    var content = $("#content");

    content.load("pages/page.php", function() {
        content.fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: I'm aware that the question indirectly is about SEO, but i'm not concerned about optimizing the findability of the site. My intention was to ask about the combination of php en javascript and the way of serving the site's content to a user or crawler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called [progressive enhancement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and is perfectly acceptable to do. It makes your content accessible to those with special needs (search engine crawlers are the ultimate special needs users).

What is a no-no is serving up different or special content to search engines for the explicit purpose of manipulating your rankings. This is not the case here.